# Explain cosmic distances to a child

Tags: soft-question, arithmetic, intuition

I seem to have lost all my sense for simple calculations. I'd like to explain to my son how long cosmic distances are. As an example:

Our Sun has a diameter of $1392684\;\text{km}$. The distance to our next star Alpha Centauri is $4.153\cdot10^{13}\;\text{km}$. Now, if you pretend the Sun to be as large as a pinhead ($1\;\text{mm}$), the distance to Alpha Centauri would be... $6.793\;\text{km}$?

Sorry for this super-trivial question, but I am just not sure enough if my result is correct or a couple of digits wrong. Am I right?

**EDIT:**
Thank you Claude for noticing my second error - the Sun has a diameter of $1392684\;\text{km}$, not $1392684000\;\text{km}$ as I wrote earlier.

Comment: The distance would be $x=\frac{distanceToAlpha}{diameterOfSun} \cdot diameterOfPinhead=\frac{4.153\cdot 10^{13}}{1.392684\cdot 10^6} mm \approx 2.982 \cdot 10^7 mm= 29.82 km$

Comment: Actually for kids you should totaly avoid numbers. Compare with distances he knows (like from your hometown to a neighbor city

Comment: There is a famous talk by Terence Tao on the "Cosmic distance ladder". The slides are here:   http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/10/the-cosmic-distance-ladder-ver-4-1/

Comment: Just tell him that, no matter how big these distances might be, they can be circumvented by using worm-holes. ;-) If he asks you what worms dug those holes, tell him that they live on Mars, or something. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [sun has a diameter](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=diameter+sun) of

$$d_{\rm Sun} = 1.39 \times 10^6 \textrm{ km}$$

The [distance to Alpha Centauri](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=distance+to+alpha+centauri) ([in km](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=distance+to+alpha+centauri#q=4.367+light+years+in+km)) is

$$d_{\rm AC} = 4.13 \times 10^{13} \textrm{ km}$$

The ratio of these quantities is

$$\frac{d_{\rm AC}}{d_{\rm Sun}} = \frac{4.13 \times 10^{13}}{1.39\times 10^6} = 2.97 \times 10^7$$

Therefore, if you had a model where the diameter of the sun was 1 mm, the distance to Alpha Centauri in the model would be 2.97 x 10^7 times greater, i.e.

$$2.97 \times 10^7 \textrm{ mm} = 29.7 \textrm{ km}$$

If you took the pinhead representing the Sun and stood next to the [Washington Monument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington_monument) in Washington, DC, then Alpha Centauri would be about halfway to Baltimore.

---

Edit, more appropriate since you live in Austria! If you stood in the center of Vienna, then Alpha Centauri would be about halfway to Bratislava.

### The Sun:

[image]

### Alpha Centauri:

[image]

Comment: So roughly $300$ foot ball fields in length.

Comment: @Ethan Indeed. Or about 350 blocks in New York City.

Comment: Thank you Chris, you made my day with these nice images!

Answer (score 3):

Going to powers will simplify. If, as you gave, the diameter of the sun **was** $1.392684\times 10^9$ km and the distance to Alpha Centauri is $4.153\times 10^{13}$ km, this makes a ratio of $29820$. So, if the diameter of the sun was $1$ mm, the distance to Alpha Centauri would be $29820$ mm, that is to say $29.820$ meters.

The problem is that the diameter of the sun is $1.392684\times 10^6$ km; the same reasoning will then bring you to $29.820$ kilometers.